# ¿Como almacenar datos en un array en Python?

Tags: python

Buen dia, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
import numpy as np
pali = np.array(['larutanosaportootropasonatural'])
pali[0]
'larutanosaportootropasonatural'
def palindromo():
if (pali[0]) == (pali[0])[::-1]:
    print("palindromo")
else:
    print("no es palindromo")
return
palindromo()
```

Lo que deseo es hacer una especie de input tipo:

```
pali = str(input("ingrese la palabra: "))
```

Y que este valor se guarde en el array al ingresar la palabra y así me la compare en la funcion, creo que tendría que quedar en valor 0 siempre

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar un elemento a un array debes utilizar `lista = numpy.append(lista, nuevo_elemento)`.

Según entiendo quieres que el input ingresado vaya en la posición cero [0], entonces el código sería el siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
entrada = input("ingrese la palabra: ")
pali = np.array([entrada])
pali = np.append(pali, entrada)

def palindromo():
  if (pali[0]) == (pali[0])[::-1]:
    print("palindromo")
  else:
    print("no es palindromo")

palindromo()
```

Comment: Es perfectamente lo que quería, gracias!!!.